# Calling delete[] inside destructor in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, destructor, assignment-operator

I Have a doubt in the following code, there is a destructor `delete line[]` inside the destructor, I just want to know if there any stack over flow for this delete which can be a result of recursive call to destructor.

```
class Line {
public:
    char *line;
    Line(const char *s = 0) {
        if (s) {
            line = new char[strlen(s)+1];
            strcpy(line, s);
        } else {
            line = 0;
        }
    }

    ~Line() {
        delete[] line; //----------> how this delete will work?
        line = 0;
    }

    Line &operator=(const Line &other) {
        std::cout <<"go"<< endl;
        delete[] line; //----------> purpose of using this delete??
        line = new char[other.len()+1];
        strcpy(line, other.line);
        return *this;
    }

    int operator<=(const Line &other) {
        int cmp = strcmp(line, other.line);
        return cmp <= 0;
    }

    int len() const {
        return strlen(line);
    }
};





int main() {
Line array[] = {Line("abc"), Line("def"),
                Line("xyz")};
   Line tmp;
  }
```

The delete inside the overloaded assignment operator is to clean the memory before assigning new memory(I have read it somewhere, correct me if I am wrong), but does this delete will call the destructor?

Please Explain

Comment: `line` is a pointer to a `char`, which don't have destructors. Calling `delete` on it will deallocate the memory you allocated and that's all.

Comment: As the answers have said, there is no recursion. However, your copy assignment code has a problem if someone does `Line l("Hello World); Line *p = &l; l = *p;`.  This is self assignment, and goes horribly wrong.  The best solution is 1.  Write a proper copy constructor.  2.  Write a specialization of std::swap for Line.  3.  copy assignment takes `other` **by value**, and just does `std::swap(*this, other); return *this;`.  If your swap is no-throw (it should be), then this offers the strong exception guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not.

This delete statement will delete the char array. The destructor of Line is only called when destroying the Line object. That is however not the case here.

The variable line and the object/class Line are different things.

The line variable is a member-variable in the Line class. So those two names seem the same but are completly different.

Answer (score 1):

`delete[] line;` pairs the `new char[strlen(s)+1];` statements in the constructor and assignment operator. Note that `delete[] line;` is a no-op if `line` is set to `nullptr`, which is what the `else` branch assignment does, although it sloppily uses `0` in place of `nullptr`.

Be assured the destructor is not called recursively. It's just that the destructor is used to release any allocated memory.

But using `std::string line;` as the class member variable, *or perhaps even the entire class itself* would be far, far easier. There are some subtle bugs in your code - *self assignment* being one of them, and the copy constructor is missing. Let the C++ Standard Library take care of all this for you. In short you could write

```
int main() {
    std::string array[] = {"abc", "def", "xyz"};
    std::string tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `delete[]` is a `char*`, ie there is no destructor called (and also there is no recursive calling of the destructor).

If you had a destructor like this:

```
 ~Line() { delete this; }   // DONT DO THIS !!! (also for other reasons it is not OK at all)
```

this would attempt to call itself recursively, but your code looks fine.

In the assignment operator

```
line = new char[other.len()+1];
```

will allocate new memory and assign a pointer (pointing to this memory) to `line`. This will cause that you have no handle to the old memory anymore and to avoid a leak you need to delete it before.

Comment: `delete this` will cause undefined behaviour if the object was not created with a new expression.

Answer (score 1):

C++ by default takes care of delete[] for char*, therefore you do not need to do anything.